# SQL missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Pretty new to SQL. Have to answer this question. I have 2 tables. "employees" and "departments"

The question is. "The employee name, head of the department (HOD), and salary for all employees whose salary is not in the range of $5,000–$ 10,000"

This is what i've tried.

```
select employee_name, hod, salary
from employees
where salary < 5000 and > 10000;
```

Says missing expression under '>' 10000;

Any ideas? Do I need to join departments?

Comment: use `salary < 5000 and salary> 10000`

Comment: we need to see the table definitions, since I'm guessing that hod is in department table, not employees table, so you will then have to join the 2 tables

Comment: @DBug, how do i edit my post? The hod is in the employees table. the only thing in departments table is DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATION.

Comment: under your post should be a little "edit" link.  If all the information you have to find is in the employees table, the @vkp comment should do it (replacing "and" with "or").  But from a data model standpoint, I would expect the head of the department to be part of the department table, not employee table, since I would assume that a department has many employees, but only one head.

Comment: @vkp Of course that condition is impossible to meet ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error, the last line needs to be (column name specified each time):

```
where salary < 5000 and salary > 10000;
```

But then it won't make sense as there's no value meeting these criteria. You need the conditions to use `or`:

```
where salary < 5000 or salary > 10000
```

to exclude salaries between 5000 and 10000.

You can also use [BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm) to achieve the same:

```
where salary not between 5000 and 10000
```

Comment: awesome thanks this did the trick. I have only been doing sql for about 2 weeks so i'm still getting use to the syntax.

Comment: Do you object to `not between 5000 and 10000)`. Some people seen to not like negations.

Comment: It's a matter of style then. I do not object to it. It's described in Oracle documentation as well: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm

Answer (score 0):

Each criteria in the `WHERE` clause needs to stand on its own, for your 2nd criteria it doesn't know what field should be `> 10000`, you have to specify:

```
select employee_name, hod, salary
from employees
where salary < 5000 
  and salary > 10000;
```

This will exclude all records since it's a per-row comparison and each record can only have one value of `salary`, so likely you want `OR` instead of `AND`, or maybe you have different fields in your actual query.

There is `BETWEEN` for defining a range of numbers/dates, but it is inclusive ie `WHERE salary BETWEEN 5000 and 10000` would include everything >= 5000 and <= 10000, so not helpful in this situation, and some prefer to avoid it altogether as it can be tricky with dates.

Comment: It needs to be or not and between conditions. and won't return anything.

Comment: @Szymon I noticed that later than I should have.

Comment: Thank you, the where salary between worked. As did the other persons post below.